# Ошибка компиляции sass

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, решил подключить библиотеку carbon ui, но она работает только вместе с sass. По проекту node 16v , react 16v , использовал CRA. Все сделал как написано в доках, но получил вот такую ошибку

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/index.scss)
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use '@carbon/react';
```

Попробовал создать новый проект , сделал все тоже самое и работает , в чем может быть конфликт?

Comment: Отредактируйте пожалуйста вопрос и вставьте код и ошибку текстом, а не скриншотами.

Comment: исправил, так лучше?

Comment: Да, постарайтесь написать [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)